# I have a method withdraw(); that doesnt work, any idea why?

Tags: java

My withdraw method doesnt work, maybe someone see things I dont see?

This is part of my abstract class Account and abstract method withdraw

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Account {
private String accountType;
private static double balance = 0;
protected int accountId;
private static int accountNumberCounter = 1000;
private ArrayList<Account> accounts;

public Account(String acType, int acNumber){
    accountType = acType;
    accountNumberCounter ++;
    accountId = accountNumberCounter;
}

public Account() {
    accountNumberCounter++;
    accountId = accountNumberCounter;
}

public abstract boolean withdraw(double value);
```

This is SavingsAccount class and its method withdraw()

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account {
private static double balance = 0;
private static final double RATE = 1.0;
private static  String accountType = "Savings Account";
private int accountId;


public SavingsAccount(){
    super();
}

public double getBalance(){
    return balance;
}

public void deposit(double amount){
    balance = balance + amount;
}

public boolean withdraw(double amount){
    if (balance<= amount){
        System.out.println("You have only" + amount + "left on your account.");
    return false;
    }
    else{
        balance -= amount;
        System.out.println("You took:" + amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Method from BankLogic as well, I think this part should be correct:

```
  public boolean withdraw(String pNo, int accountId, double amount){
    for(Customer pers: customerList) {
        if (pers.getPersonalNumber().equals(pNo)) {
            for (Account account : pers.getAllAccounts()) {
                if (account.getAccountNumber() == accountId) {
                    account.withdraw(amount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you getting some errors? If so, post the stacktrace. If not, what is the expected vs actual output?

Comment: The code looks fine to me, did you try debugging it?

Comment: The fact that your field for balance is static cannot be correct. Every Account should have its own balance, but with a static field they all share the same balance.

Comment: `private STATIC double balance` means all your accounts have the same balance...

Comment: You need to learn to use a debugger. Fo all we know, maybe you don't use the correct personnal number or accound id. I have a strange déjà-vu feeling on this code...

Comment: It doesnt pass this test

Comment: private boolean testingWithdraw(String pNr, int accountId, double amount)
       {
        System.out.println("withdraw(" + pNr + "," + accountId + "," + amount + ")");
        return bank.withdraw(pNr, accountId, amount);
    }

Comment: deposit works fine

Comment: the answer is probably the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264572/any-idea-why-i-can-not-assign-a-unique-number-to-my-savingsaccount). Your variables shouldn't be `static`. We you post a failing test, post it **in the question** and with the values used. Your previous comment gives no more information

Comment: I fixed this with static but still doesnt work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
private boolean testingWithdraw(String pNr, int accountId, double amount) {
    System.out.println("withdraw(" + pNr + "," + accountId + "," + amount + ")");
    return bank.withdraw(pNr, accountId, amount);
}
```

That's because inside bank withdraw method, you return false, even if it is success.

```
 public boolean withdraw(String pNo, int accountId, double amount){
    for(Customer pers: customerList) {
        if (pers.getPersonalNumber().equals(pNo)) {
            for (Account account : pers.getAllAccounts()) {
                if (account.getAccountNumber() == accountId) {
                    account.withdraw(amount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false; //this should be true. this denotes  the whole process
}
```

If you want to maintain the status of updation of each accouunt, then you may use a map of (String,boolean) to maintaion id->updation status

Comment: no, this should remain to `false` as it means there was no account found. Instead there should be a return on the call to `account.withdraw` -> `return account.withdraw(amount);`

Comment: with your answer, @MayJay now has a code that will always return true even if the account balance is less than the amount withdrawn

Comment: It works but isnt it gonna always return true?

Comment: Thanks it works better, now I get other errors :o :)))

Comment: @jhamon reply @ your first comment -> it will be true if all updations success or there was no account to update. therefore its fine

Comment: @jhamon @ your second comment -> thats why i said he has to maintaion account id-wise updation status

Comment: @ChiranK. If a method contains only a single `return` and the value returned is a constant `true`, I'm quite sure it will always return `true`. If there is no account to update, why would you return `true`, which judging by the code means "success"? (This also applies in concrete real life case. Do you expect your bank to give you a success message when you try to withdraw money from a non-existant account/client ?)

Comment: @jhamon thats why i said, if he wants to check whether the processing success/failed he can do this, otherwise has to maintain account-wise

Comment: you don't seem to understand the check is litteraly the `account.withdraw` and always returning true is useless and in your case he better makes the `bank.withdraw` return `void` instead of a wrong flag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure what you mean by it's not working, but I see two problems.

1. Balance shouldn't be static. It should be a class variable that has its own value for each object created.
2. In your withdraw-method you are saying "You have only" + amount + "left on your account.", while it should be balance instead of amount.

Hope I could help.

Comment: removed static, still the same

Comment: What do you mean by "still the same"? What is not working? Can you put an error code in here?

Comment: This test doesnt pass and print this output:

Comment: personalNumber  = "7505121231";
        accountNumber   = 1005;
        amount    = 100;
        if(!testingWithdraw(personalNumber, accountNumber, amount))
            System.err.println("Error: withdraw("+personalNumber + "," + accountNumber + "," + amount+")");

Answer (score 0):

You never return the result of the withdraw method.

Change the bank code to return the value from the account's withdraw method and it should be fine (as you already fix the `static` issue)

```
public boolean withdraw(String pNo, int accountId, double amount){
    for(Customer pers: customerList) {
        if (pers.getPersonalNumber().equals(pNo)) {
            for (Account account : pers.getAllAccounts()) {
                if (account.getAccountNumber() == accountId) {
                    return account.withdraw(amount); // return the account withdrawing value
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // false as no account found if this line is reached
}
```